# How can I add a css class to a Primefaces MenuButton container?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

Applying a styleClass to the MenuButton seems to only apply it to the button itself and not the container of the menu items.  Anyone have a workaround for adding a class to this div?

Using PrimeFaces 3.5

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ? If you download the [developer's guide](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html) and scroll down to the skinning section of MenuButton you will find the names of style classes. You can override rules from there.

Comment: Either you can add css to menuItem or you can change/override css for css class `ui-menu` to apply of container div.